# Return to previous isotope filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am currently using the jquery Isoptope plugin in my application. I am filter a set of items on initial load. The problem I run into is that when I use my search that also utilizes the Isoptope plugin it will not return to the initial filter after I am done searching, thus displaying all of the items instead of the initial filtered list. Is there a way to set up multiple filters so that the search will only filter on the initial filtered Items?

Here is the searching implementation that I am using: https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/107#issuecomment-2673702